# Low-energy effective actions in string theory: agreement between beta-function vs. scattering-based derivations?

Tags: string-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

In string theory, in my limited understanding, starting with the worldsheet theory, we have at least two methods for deriving the low-energy effective action on the target spacetime. We can either

1. Calculate the beta-functions of the worldsheet theory coupled to the spacetime fields, then set them to zero (i.e. demand Weyl-invariance) to obtain EOM for the fields, and then ask which action reproduces those EOM.
2. Calculate string scattering in perturbation theory using the worldsheet theory, and then ask for an action which reproduces those scattering amplitudes.

These two derivations of the low-energy effective action agree (at least to low order in $\alpha'$ and $g_s$) because "string theory is consistent"; see e.g. [Tong's notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html), p168. Without assuming consistency, is there some mathematical reason to expect these calculations agree?  (Are they secretly the same calculation?) In particular, can we prove these derivations of the low-energy effective action agree at higher orders in $g_s$ and $\alpha'$?

Comment: The idea is that, in (bosonic) string theory, we can exponentiate the massless vertex operator and obtain a marginal deformation to the worldsheet CFT. Conversely, we can expand a marginal deformation around some background and obtain massless vertex operator sitting downstairs.